# Freeze table first two column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with bit complicated structure as it has has colspan with multiple headers. I need to fix my table first two column and rest should be scrollable horizontally. I tried various examples to freeze column but does not work as expected. Below are the links that I referred.

I want everything to be fixed under Activity and indicator description header

- [Nested table: Freeze first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775154/nested-table-freeze-first-column)
- [How do I create an HTML table with a fixed/frozen left column and a scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-a-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-a-scrollable-b)

```html
<table class="Fixed" border="1" width="auto;" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 18%;text-align: center;">Activity and indicator description</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 5%;text-align: center;"></th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;" colspan="2">FY2021</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2022</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2023</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2024</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;"  colspan="2">Cumulative</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2"> Life of project</td>
        
    </tr>
    
    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Activity</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Indicator</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Baseline</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th style="font-style: italic;">Project Objective 1: Identify and support nascent and grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks in Latin America and the Caribbean. </th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>1.1: Identify grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks throughout the LAC region.</td>
        <td>1.1.1: Number of new actors (organizations and individuals) across the region identified</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: put it in a code snippet

Comment: Yea, you should make it a runnable snippet so people can see the thing here; also include *more* of the document than just the table, because unless the `<table>` is the **only** thing inside the `<body>`, the different solutions will have different effects on the stuff around the `<table>`. Are you simply trying to present this table in a nice way; or are you building a script that reproduces the table dynamically based on new information; or is this table just the result of some export in another program (and ifso do you have to repeat it often or not)

Comment: The reason i asked the last point is, it is pretty odd to see so much CSS inlined into the HTML as opposed to using a stylesheet (not to mention a couple old school html-styling attributes). It hints at either being generated by a `File->Save as .html` feature in some program; or at being part of e-mail message; or just being written when Airwolf was still popular on TV.

Comment: @Raxi Yeah I have used inline css because that's not the final version. 
PS I know it is an old school html styling, but let's just get onto the main issue. :)

Comment: Yea the old school thing wasn't ment as a problem; more as catalyst for asking about the context of the table; The inline CSS is more problematic because it makes changing the layout a massive pain in the ass (because any change has to be applied in 50 places manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't recommend you to inline your `CSS` like that.
You're unnecessarily repeating yourself hundreds of time.

You said "I have used inline css because that's not the final version" but that is not a valid reason. It's going to be much harder for you to refactor all your code the longer you wait.

There is a great article you should read about this matter: [A short guide on when and when not to use inline CSS styles in HTML (Inline Styles in HTML on Code Academy)](https://www.codecademy.com/article/html-inline-styles)

Also, you really should learn more about `CSS Frameworks`, looks like you would love them, check: [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/), [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), ... [Here an article that lists the best CSS Frameworks in 2021 (on Dev To)](https://dev.to/theme_selection/best-css-frameworks-in-2020-1jjh)

Second, the CSS property you're looking for is `position: sticky` : [Sticky Positioning on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning)

Here is a snippet (note that I didn't inline the style, I have added some `classes` on the `sticky` elements)

To make everything more dynamic you could even make the vertical scolling header sticky as well.

```css
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
}
.sticky_two{
  position: sticky;
  background: white;
  left: 79.78px ; /* width of first element + spacing */
}
.th{
  background: rgb(22, 50, 92);
}
```

```html
<table class="Fixed" border="1" width="auto;" style="table-layout:fixed">
                    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
                        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 18%;text-align: center;" class="sticky th">Activity and indicator description</th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 5%;text-align: center;"></th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;" colspan="2">FY2021</th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2022</th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2023</th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2024</th>
                        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;"  colspan="2">Cumulative</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;"></td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2"> Life of project</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" class="sticky th">Activity</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" class="sticky_two th">Indicator</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Baseline</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                        
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="sticky" style="font-style: italic;">Project Objective 1: Identify and support nascent and grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks in Latin America and the Caribbean. </th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sticky">1.1: Identify grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks throughout the LAC region.</td>
                        <td class="sticky_two">1.1.1: Number of new actors (organizations and individuals) across the region identified</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sticky" rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
                        <td class="sticky_two" >1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and also for the points that you made me realized. I would really make sure to use them from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

- Change `<table class="Fixed" border="1" width="auto;" style="table-layout:fixed">` to `<table class="Fixed">` (attributes will move to stylesheet)
- add `<thead> ... </thead>` around the 1st to 3rd  `<tr>`'s
- add `<tbody> ... </tbody>` around the 4th to last `<tr>`'s
- now the `<thead>` section can be made sticky so it remains when scrolling down
- to do that, add a little stylesheet like:

_

```
table.Fixed         { table-layout:fixed; width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table.Fixed thead   { position: sticky; top: 0; }
table.Fixed, 
table.Fixed th, 
table.Fixed td      { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid rgb(22, 50, 92); }
```

Results:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
body                { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table.Fixed         { table-layout:fixed; width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table.Fixed thead   { position: sticky; top: 0; }
table.Fixed, 
table.Fixed th, 
table.Fixed td      { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid rgb(22, 50, 92); }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<table class="Fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 18%;text-align: center;">Activity and indicator description</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 5%;text-align: center;"></th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;" colspan="2">FY2021</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2022</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2023</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 25%;text-align: center;" colspan="8">FY2024</th>
        <th style="color:#FFFFFF;width: 7%;text-align: center;"  colspan="2">Cumulative</th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 1</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 2</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 3</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2">Qtr 4</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;" colspan="2"> Life of project</td>

    </tr>
    <tr style="background: rgb(22, 50, 92);">
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Activity</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Indicator</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Baseline</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>

        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Target</td>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;">Actual</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th style="font-style: italic;">Project Objective 1: Identify and support nascent and grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks in Latin America and the Caribbean. </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1.1: Identify grassroots CSOs, activists, and community networks throughout the LAC region.</td>
        <td>1.1.1: Number of new actors (organizations and individuals) across the region identified</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1.2: Conduct annual virtual Innovation Labs.</td>   
        <td>1.2.1: Number of individuals or organizations selected to participate in innovation labs </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```